# Git hook not working

Tags: git, gerrit, githooks

My git hook does not seem to be working. Namely a `commit-msg` hook from gerrit.

The `commit-msg` hook exist in `<repo>/.git/hooks/` and has proper syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure your hook files are executable. If you use i.e. `curl` to download hooks, make sure you `chmod +x` them.

```
$ pwd
<repo>/.git/hooks
$ chmod +x commit-msg
```

If you use `scp` to get your hooks, the flag `-p` might set proper modes for you.

Comment: Setting the executable flag is mentioned in the Gerrit documentation.

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html

Comment: Just adding +x might be not enough. In may case the hook wasn't working until I changed permissions to 755 like the rest of hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912695/git-pre-and-post-commit-hooks-not-running). It could be that `core.hooksPath` has been set to another path than `$GIT_DIR/hooks`, making your hooks in that folder ignored.