# git pre- and post- commit hooks not running

Tags: git

What could cause my git pre- and post- commit hooks to not run?

(please note: this question is not a duplicate; the answer to each of the other questions is either `chmod +x` or "don't have a file extension", and neither are the issue here)

They are executable:

`$ ls -alh .git/hooks/*-commit
-rwxr-xr-x  … .git/hooks/post-commit
-rwxr-xr-x  … .git/hooks/pre-commit`

And this is the content of each of them:

`#!/bin/sh
echo "$0 IS RUNNING"
exit 1`

Running them manually works:

`$ .git/hooks/pre-commit
.git/hooks/pre-commit IS RUNNING`

But they aren't run by `git` on commit:

`$ git commit -am "Test hooks"
[master d17c0f38] Test hooks
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)`

This is with git 2.16.2

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I have seen for instance the config `core.hooksPath` being set to another path than `$GIT_DIR/hooks`, making your hooks in that folder ignored.

Check your  `git config core.hooksPath` output, and more generally  `git config -l` for any out of the ordinary settings.

Note that a [`git commit -n` would skip the pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230886/6309).

**Edit** by wolever:

I've added this to the scripts in my `core.hooksPath` directory, which will run the repo's hooks if they exist:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu
hook_name="$(basename "$0")"
hook_script=".git/hooks/$hook_name"
[ -e "$hook_script" ] && "$hook_script"
exit 0
```

Comment: Ahh yep, that's it! I had set it a while ago, and assumed it would run in addition to local hooks, not instead of. You seem to be correct - if `core.hooksPath` is present, then `.git/hooks/` is never checked (even if the `core.hooksPath` is missing a hook script).

Comment: @DavidWolever Well done. You do post challenging questions!

Comment: Let's say there's no `core.hooksPath` at all. But, you've found that running `git config --list --show-origin` shows you your global config location and now you just want every single project to always run the `pre-commit` hook to do the same thing (in my case to run tests if I forgot to). Where should I set my global hooks path AND how to tell the script that runs `npm test -- --updateSnapshots` to first cd to the specific project's root dir?

Comment: @NeilGuyLindberg Where: any folder you want, in order to host your hooks, including the pre-commit one. But since it takes no args, you cannot find the root folder of a specific project. Installing it locally, like this one does, is safer: https://pre-commit.com/

Comment: This solved my problem. I thought `hooksPath` was additive.

Comment: Oh my! Husky seem to do this, and suddenly break people's own private repo-hooks. That's quite the nasty surprise.

Comment: I was surprised this was the case even with a `hooksPath` that does not exist! (Copy pasted my `.gitConfig` from another computer without thinking). No errors or anything, just... local git hooks didn't work. Amazing!

Answer (score 18):

In my case `core.hooksPath` in `projRootDir/.git/config` was set incorrectly. Removing the entry from config file did the trick

Comment: This. Just remove the hooksPath entry for your local config file

Answer (score 10):

Executing this command in project(repository) root should fix the probem

```
git config --local core.hooksPath .git/hooks
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case of [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) in particular, the pre-commit hook was not running because in that particular repo I had done `pip install pre-commit`, but not `pre-commit install` to install it into `.git/hooks/pre-commit`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Husky like me to set git hooks, ensure `git config core.hooksPath` returns `.husky`.

Afterwards, if you get error `hint: The '.husky/pre-commit' hook was ignored because it's not set as executable.`, then you need to set the hook files to be executable like so:

```
cd .husky
chmod +x pre-commit
```

Answer (score -1):

I just want to add that if you're having any confusion about what your path is to your git hooks then open your git hooks file with your terminal and run `pwd` or `cd` from your terminal to get the absolute path and use that for your `hooksPath =`

Answer (score -1):

Check that your version of Git is greater than 2.9.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Can't edit, but the missing detail here is that Git versions below 2.9 don't support `core.hooksPath`. Therefore, it's possible someone might encounter this problem when attempting to run hooks from a non-standard location (as they might erroneously assume `core.hooksPath` works, because Git does not tell you if a configuration option is unused)

Comment: As of Jun 2023, git is only at version 2.41.0.  (see https://github.com/git/git/tags)
Are you using a different git or did you specify the wrong version #?